# Is it possible to limit rows of joined table only using Laravel Query Builder?

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I need to get a list of row from main query considering whether last record of another table satisfy the condition.

Let's say **Table A** has one to many relationship with **Table B** and **Table B** has one to one  relationship with **Table C**

I want to get list of records from **Table A** where last record in **Table B** and **Table C** satisfy given condition(some column in B and C).

**-UPDATE-**

**Table A**

id | ac1 | ac2

**Table B**

id | table_a_id | bc1 | bc2

**Table C**

id | table_b_id | cc1 | cc2

I want all the records from Table A where last record for each in Table B and C satisfy the condition. (where last record has bc1 = "GIVEN" and cc1 = "GIVEN")

Comment: Please add sample data for all tables, to better explain what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisenQuestion is updated

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your request, you can use something similar to this query

```
$query = A::leftjoin('B', 'A.id', '=', 'B.table_a_id')
    ->leftjoin('C', 'A.id', '=', 'C.table_b_id')
    ->where('B.bc1', 'GIVEN')
    ->where('C.cc1', 'GIVEN')
    ->select(
        'A.*',
        'B.bc1',
        'C.cc1'
    )
    ->get();
```

Comment: No, let's assume Table A has users records. There can be multiple records for each user  in B and C. Among them I need to check whether latest row in B and C for particular user   match with the given condition.
In your suggestion it just apply the condition on all the joined records.